# Why can't I get rid of the 'X' button on my LWC Modal? I have a 'Cancel' lightning button so the 'X' is not needed

Tags: lightning-web-components, html, button, modal

I have a LWC quick action on my Salesforce record page. I have added a 'Cancel' lightning button that will close the modal, so I need to remove or hide the big 'X' that shows up outside of the modal. I have tried many different CSS selectors and html classes like 'display:none' and 'slds-hidden' but it is still showing up.

```
<template>
    <section role="dialog" tabindex="-1" aria-modal="true" aria-labelledby="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal slds-fade-in-open">
        <div id="CERSModal" class="slds-modal__container">
<!--                    <button style="display:none" class="slds-button slds-button_icon slds-modal__close slds-button_icon-inverse">-->
<!--                        <svg style="display:none" class="slds-button__icon slds-button__icon_large" aria-hidden="true">-->
<!--                            <use style="display:none" xlink:href="/assets/icons/utility-sprite/svg/symbols.svg#close"></use>-->
<!--                        </svg>-->
<!--                        <span style="display:none" class="slds-assistive-text">Cancel and close</span>-->
<!--                    </button>-->
            <div class="slds-modal__header">
                <h1 id="modal-heading-01" class="slds-modal__title slds-hyphenate">Generate CERS File</h1>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__content slds-p-around_medium" id="modal-content-id-1">
                <p><b>Enter the required information below.
                </b></p>
                <div class="slds-p-around_x-small lgc-bg">
                    <lightning-input class="customInputField" label="Carrier Name"  type="text" value={carrierName} onchange={carrierNameChange} required="true"></lightning-input>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-p-around_x-small lgc-bg">
                    <lightning-input class="customInputField" label="Document Number" type="text" value={documentNo} onchange={documentNumberChange} required="true"></lightning-input>
                </div>
                <div class="slds-p-around_x-small lgc-bg">
                    <lightning-input class="customInputField" label="Form Key Value"  type="text" value={formKeyValue} onchange={formKeyValueChange} required="true"></lightning-input>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="slds-modal__footer">
                <button class="slds-button slds-button_neutral" aria-label="Cancel and close" onclick={closeModal}>Cancel</button>
                <lightning-button variant="brand"
                                  label="Generate File"
                                  title="Generate File"
                                  onclick={downloadClick}
                                  class="slds-m-left_x-small">
                </lightning-button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
</template>
```

Screenshot: [image: open modal]

Is it possible to hide the 'X' that is on the side? It is off center and not needed. There is no CSS added right now as nothing was working.

Config File:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">
 <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>
 <description>Trac Generate Txt File</description>
 <isExposed>true</isExposed>
 <targets>
 <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
 <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
 </targets>
 <targetConfigs>
 <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
 <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
 </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
 <masterLabel>Trac Generate Txt File</masterLabel>
</LightningComponentBundle>
```

Comment: What's the config file look like for this component?

Comment: <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<LightningComponentBundle xmlns="http://soap.sforce.com/2006/04/metadata">

 <apiVersion>54.0</apiVersion>

 <description>Trac Generate Txt File</description>
 <isExposed>true</isExposed>
 <targets>
 <target>lightning__RecordPage</target>
 <target>lightning__RecordAction</target>
 </targets>
 <targetConfigs>
 <targetConfig targets="lightning__RecordAction">
 <actionType>ScreenAction</actionType>
 </targetConfig>
 </targetConfigs>
 <masterLabel>Trac Generate Txt File</masterLabel>

</LightningComponentBundle>

Comment: Sorry for the bad formatting on the above comment, wouldn't let me upload an image in a comment and it autoformats to same lines

Comment: You can, and we recommend you do, [edit] your question to include additional information. Comments are mostly meant to ask clarifying questions and may be cleaned up at any time.

Comment: Thanks for the tip, original question has been edited to include config file.

Answer (score 3):

`lightning__RecordAction` with `actionType` set to `ScreenAction` provides a modal for you. You don't need to use SLDS modal markup when you use this type. See [`lightning-quick-action-panel`](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning-quick-action-panel/documentation) for an example of how you're meant to build a quick action. If you use this component, the X, while redundant, will be placed in its proper position on the upper-right corner of your component's popup. Unfortunately, you cannot suppress this feature, as it is part of the standard UI.

Comment: Thank you! Using lightning-quick-action-panel worked.

Comment: @mcook Glad I could help!